# Windows 8 locked because the password were lost, how can I change it without needing to reinstall it?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, login

I installed Windows 8 on my mother's notebook, she typed a new password for her and she lost it, she can't remember what she typed and no notes about it were made(my fault), now her Windows 8 installation just keep locked on logon/password screen.

How can I change the Windows 8 password for her account, reset the password or recovery the password without needing to reinstall entire Windows 8?

Could I just create another new account on the same computer from the safe mode or something like this?

PS: No live account was related to her Windows 8 account as far no account was registered on Windows 8 Store.

Comment: Unless you created a recovery password disk then your at the mercy of third-party solutions. You should be able to log into the built-in Administrator account and change the password to the local account that way. You at the very least will have more options. Sadly I forget if the Administrator account is enabled or disabled by default.  The answer from week in this question seems like the best solution: http://superuser.com/questions/515023/resetting-windows-8-password?rq=1

Comment: You could log into the computer with your windows live account I think. Not sure though. This is an awesome tool http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/ but I've only tested it upto windows 7. Take a crack at it. All the best.

Comment: @nikhil - The author clearly indicates that a Microsoft Account was NOT setup. Furthermore that would only allow the user to log into their Microsoft Account account not the local account.  I have not fully tested if the profiles are seperate or not been meaning to do that.

Comment: Ok I said I wasn't sure and I stand corrected. Thanks, he/she can try the other solution.

Comment: I followed the instructions in this video. It is simplier and cleaner ;-) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2-NK3EyigU

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout Hirens bootdisk. 
http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd

I've made several custom bootdisks for various troubleshooting situations.  There are a variety of password reset utilities you can use along with a plethora of other useful utilities.

Comment: Hiren disks can solve all sorts of problems

Answer (score 4):

Boot to a live cd, navigate to c:\windows\system32\, rename osk.exe to osk1.exe, rename cmd.exe to osk.exe, boot to windows and use utility manager menu in the lower left to launch on screen keyboard, this actually gives you a command prompt.  Type compmgmt.msc at the prompt and then in users and groups make any changes you wish.  Do not forget to rename the files back

Answer (score -1):

Windows 8 cannot be booted in safe mode in this scenario unless you had legacy boot enabled.

I.e. run `bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy` in elevated command prompt. What can be tried is resetting the password online if in case of a Microsoft account; else, booting into recovery environment and then replacing `osk.exe` with `cmd.exe` can be helpful after booting from Windows 8 disc.

Further details about resetting the password for Windows 8 can be found at [Reset Windows 8 password](http://tools.atechmate.com/windows8pass.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry.