# Reset Windows 8.1 password of another hard drive?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, passwords

I have a transformer notebook (ASUS T100A) and am resorting to mounting the HDD in another windows 8 computer.

Is it possible to change the password of that windows 8 installation like you would in Linux systems?

Although I'm unsure if Windows 8 is installed on the HDD or is it somewhere in the tablet itself?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/515023/resetting-windows-8-password

Comment: This is almost similar to the one above.

Comment: Mounting the drive to extract files is different to resetting a user password... which of the two are you attempting to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the only method but this worked for me:

Boot from a Windows 8 installer and invoker a command prompt. Determine the drive letter of the Windows 8 system that you want to change the password of. Let's use D: as an example:

```
1. Temporarily copy D:\windows\system32\utilman.exe somewhere.
2. Rename D:\windows\system32\cmd.exe to D:\windows\system32\utilman.exe
3. Reboot
```

utilman.exe is the program that is invoked when you click that accessibility icon in the bottom left corner of the login screen. By renaming cmd.exe to utilman.exe, when that icon is clicked, a command prompt invokes instead. From there any local password can be changed (admin rights required?).

```
net user <someone> *
```

[William](https://superuser.com/users/4386/william-hilsum) actually posted this solution in [a very similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/515023/resetting-windows-8-password)